# How do I display other info on page using only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm building my website using only html and css. I've read several tutorials and did my research, but now I'm stuck in an area. I have created a menu on top of my page using `ul` and `li` and within the `li` are the links. the links themselves hold more info other than just the link. There is a `span` after them, and the `span` shows info that I will show after the user clicks on the link. I use `a:focus` for the info to show on the page. So the structure is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">RESUME
        <span class="resume">
            blah blah blah
        </span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">My artwork
        <span class="artwork_area">
            blah blah blah
        </span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

While it's fine that the resume section works well with `a:focus`, and getting it to display on the page only after the user clicks on it, it will not work the same with 'my artwork' because I need to have more links inside that section. I know that it's not allowed to have links nested inside other links, so how can I get the code to look like this?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">RESUME
        <span class="resume">blah blah blah</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1">My artwork</a><!--notice how the link ends here-->
        <span class="artwork_area">
            <p>blah blah blah
            <a href="assets/images/image1.jpg"><img src="assets/images/large_image1.jpg"/>Pic1</a>
            <a href="assets/images/image2.jpg" ><img src="assets/images/large_image1.jpg"/>Pic2</a>
            </p>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to make that `span` section appear without nesting it inside the link, but that won't be acceptable to nest another link within it.
I've only been reading and putting to practice html and css for about 3 weeks, so I'm not that savvy yet. I would really like to do my website in only html and css as I see it is more convenient and loads much faster. I made a short [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tZlt6qTkLA&hd=1) video to explain how it currently looks.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why you aren't using javascript/jquery? (it will make this type of stuff much easier)

Comment: Why is it that you can't nest the action links?

Comment: @flynfish like i mentioned earlier i just started getting into html and css and its been 3 weeks so far. Ive read about javascript but i have not really felt like i have gotten a good grip unto html and/or css so i would feel like javascript is a lil too much for atm. Though it reminds me of c++.

Comment: @mouters well u can't nest a link inside another link...its stated in the guidelines for links.

Comment: d'oh! I've just twigged what your saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

I had a quick look on the [w3schools css selector reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and noted the `element+element` selector with example:

```
div+p -> Selects all <p> elements that are placed immediately after <div> elements
```

So I tried the following style and it works for your second example

```
a:focus+span {
   display:block;
}
```

**And The Rest Of It**

I've made an assumption on what your css looks like - perhaps you could edit your question to show this so that your example is complete.

But based on the html example you provided the following works for both cases.

```
<style>
li>span {
    display:none;
}

li>a:focus span {
    display:block;
}

li>a:focus+span {
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Thinking about it if you were to make things consistent so that you never nested the `span` inside the action link, you could remove the `a:focus span` selector. Your *resume* list-item would become:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" tabindex="1">RESUME</a>
    <span class="resume">blah blah blah</span>
</li>
```

Also if you haven't already done so you might want to give the list-item elements of your menu system a common class eg `menu-item` so as to constrain css further. Here the intent is to always show the last list-item *Outside*.

```
<style>
li.menu-item>span {
    display:none;
}

li.menu-item>a:focus+span {
    display:block;
}
</style>

...

<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        ... Resume 
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        ... My artwork
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" tabindex="1">Outside</a>
        <span class="resume">outside stuff which is always shown</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

One final thing; I noticed that clicking on one of the image action links breaks the whole thing since the main action link is hidden again. From what I can see there's no `parent-from-child` selector so I'm not sure at this stage how this will work for you. Anyways I think the `element+element` selector  answers your specific question.

Comment: Really good stuff here! I had to take a snippet of my code to test it out and see how it works and yea it is works really well. I got the answer I was looking for. I can now nest a link inside of the description section( span ) of that link.

I had another question though because I notice this, is there a way that when I click on the link ( found in the span ) to not close the entire span section that it is in? other than that this is working really well.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the `:target` pseudo element. This way you could hide the content in an `div` with an `id` and then link to this `id` with the #-sign. Have a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2HMR/). It messes up jsfiddle a bit but works good when you do it on your own page.

Here is a nice read on the `:target` pseudo element. [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/)

Hope this can help you.

**Update**
Here's a better [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2HMR/2/)

Comment: I like those links and were quite helpful and understanding of the :target pseudo element. But i would need this to be only visible when the parent link is clicked on and when they click away i need it to disappear;hence the importance of :focus and its important to me to not have multiple html files on my server when i know i can have them all in 1 document. got any more ideas? or a way to make :focus happen on a :target?

Comment: No, not that I know of. Not without JavaScript anyway, but it seems like [mouters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11220105/1397073) have figured something out for you.