# Large image will not remain after I click on thumbnail. HTML & CSS only

Tags: html, css

So I recently made another post and I felt it was clearly answered, here's the link ( [Prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214790/how-do-i-display-other-info-on-page-using-only-css-and-html/11220105#11220105) ) and while it does explain and achieve what I wanted to know, it created a new issue for me. So I thought it would be best to create a new post for this particular question.
 My question is that when I created my navmenu and had a link in there, so that when you click on it it shows u the div section. In that section I have a thumbnail image. I want to make it clickable so that when you click on it the large image appears on the side. And while I can do this with hover, I would also like it ( the large image ) to remain there if the user wants to click on the thumbnail. I also have an anchor on the description of the large image if the user wants to see the full resolution of the image. The problem is that when I click on the thumbnail the entire Div section disappears...which is weird. Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-aAydZqj44&hd=1) showing what I mean. Heres also my code for how I have it on my dummy page:

here is my [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/n6f4Y/)

Please keep in mind that I'm new at html and css and really would just like to do my portfolio site in these 2 languages. I will later on move into javascript once I get a better grip and understanding of css and html. been doing this for about a lil over 3 weeks now. Thanks ahead of time for reading all of this and potentially helping out.

Comment: Is it ok to do this using jquery.

Comment: @svs Im sure its easier in the other languages but I would really want to keep this in css and html as those are the ones im comfortable with.

Comment: Actually its not easy or possible to do something with click event using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now you can used to **`check box`** and than it's **possible**

Please check to this **demo i created** http://jsfiddle.net/n6f4Y/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

<h1>Welcome to Erimagination!</h1>
<hr id="top_hr">

<ul id="navmenu">

    <!-- This is my PORTFOLIO section -->
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="portfolio"/>
        <label for="portfolio">Portfolio</label>
        <span class="des_am"><h3>Latest Work</h3><br>
            <p>check out this image:
            <br>
                <a href="#"><img class="thumb_image" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f6ba1c2b27d3a607d894c70ba1be0f85?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="" ></a>
                <span class="large_image"><img src="files/pictures/photoshop/brit_airways.jpg" alt="">
                    <br>This is the larger version of the thumbnail. If you would like to see the full
                    version you can click <a href="#" style="text-decoration:underline; color:blue;"><i>HERE</i></a>
                </span>
            </p>
        </span>
    </li>
    <!-- PORTFOLIO ends -->

</ul>


</div>
```

**Css**

```
/* Reset things */
    *{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    /* The pages width and height plus bkg color and margins */
    #container{
        width: 960px;
        height: 960px;
        background:#ABC;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

    /* minor stuff */
    a{ text-decoration: none; color:red; }
    ul, li{ list-style-type:none }      



    /*===================================
        set the nav menu link stuff
    ===================================*/
    #navmenu{
        float:left;
        margin-left: 50px;
        background: white;
        width:80px;
        height:25px;
        line-height:25px;
        padding:3px;
    }

    #navmenu a:hover{ color:green; }
    #navmenu a:focus{  font-size:16pt; text-decoration:underline; color:green; }


    /* Set stuff up in our span but hide it */
    li > span{
        display:none;
        width:875px;
        height:800px;
        float:left;
        background:white;
        color:grey;
        text-indent:15px;
        padding-right:3px;
        padding-left:6px;
        margin-top:30px;
    }

    /* show span stuff when link is clicked on */
li > input[type="checkbox"]{
display:none;
}  
li  label{
cursor:pointer;
}

li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span{ display:block; }

    /* Thumbnail parameters when link is clicked */
    li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span .thumb_image{
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        background:red;
        outline:1px solid red;
    }

    /* minor thumnail stuff */
    li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span .thumb_image:hover{ outline:3px solid rgba(0,255,0, 1); }



    /* ===================================
        large image stuff parameters
    =====================================*/

    /* Set up and  Hide large image with z-index */
    li > input[type="checkbox"] + label + span span{
        z-index:-200;
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        color:black;
        width:600px;
        padding:4px;
        position:absolute;
        background:rgba( 255, 250, 108, .25);
        outline:1px solid darkgrey;
        text-align:center;
        margin: -0px 0 0 150px;
    }

    /* bring large image into view when thumbnail is hovered */
    li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span a:focus+span, li > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label + span a:hover+span{ z-index:10; }

    /*
    li >a:focus+span .thumb_image:hover+.large_image{ z-index:10; }

    li > a+span .large_image{
        z-index:-200;
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        color:black;
        width:600px;
        padding:4px;
        position:absolute;
        background:rgba( 255, 20, 108, .5);
        border:1px solid black;
        text-align:center;
        margin: -0px 0 0 175px;
    }
    */
```

Comment: @rohit Azad ah while the jfiddle doesnt work i simply copy and pasted the stuff in a duplicate of my dummy page html file and it works magically. Thanks.